# Configurable WCF service URL for jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML5 page which uses jQuery to call a WCF service.
Is there any way to make the web service URL configurable instead of hard-coding the URL in the jQuery code ?

Comment: can you show up the list of url's?

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do so, you can create a config.js file that holds all your variables declarations including your:

```
var serviceUrl= "http://myservice/";
```

And then, of course, you can make all the transformations you want to create your url

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want to have a configurable value on the client side, you can do the following:

1- Create a hidden field and assign a value to it from server side.
2- get and use the value in the JavaScript or jquery.

```
var wcfurl = $('#hfWCFURL').val();
```